# Не получается изменить качество записи видео при работе с камерой

Tags: java, android

Вообщем,пытаюсь изменить качество видео при записи,но ничего не выходит. 
В логах вижу  use: width = 1920 height = 1080 а на деле 800х480.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    mRecordingStatus = false;
    mServiceCamera = MainActivity.mCameraBack;
    mSurfaceView = MainActivity.mSurfaceView;
    mSurfaceHolder =
            MainActivity.mSurfaceHolder;// для обновления изображения из фоновых потоков.

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(
        Intent intent) {//возвращает канал связи, который используют клиенты, чтобы взаимодействовать со службой.
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    if (mRecordingStatus == false) {
        startRecording();
    }

    return START_STICKY;//будет вызываться при повторном запуске сервиса после преждевременного завершения работы.
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopRecording();
    mRecordingStatus = false;

    super.onDestroy();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean startRecording() {

    try {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           // mServiceCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            mServiceCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);

        //mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters params =
                mServiceCamera.getParameters();//получить текущие настройки камеры.
        params.set("cam_mode", 1);
        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
        Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

        final List<Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(1);
        mPreviewSize.width = 1920;
        mPreviewSize.height = 1080;
        Log.v(TAG, "use: width = " + mPreviewSize.width + " height = " + mPreviewSize.height);

        p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

        try {
            mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mServiceCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mServiceCamera.lock();
        mServiceCamera.unlock();

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        String externalFilesDir = new String(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        //mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getExternalFilesDir(externalFilesDir) + "BLE_Video_Record_" +  System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4");
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/video.mp4");
        //            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get( CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        // mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1920, 1080);

        // mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start();

        mRecordingStatus = true;

        return true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        String err = (e.getMessage() == null) ? "SD Card failed" : e.getMessage();
        Log.e("sdcard-err2:", err);

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void stopRecording() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        mServiceCamera.reconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!mRecordingStatus) {
        return;
    }
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.reset();

    mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
    mMediaRecorder.release();

    mServiceCamera.release();
    mServiceCamera = null;
}
```

}

Запускаю так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecorderService.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            startService(intent);
            finish();
```